# Split the URL from a string using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my string value:

var _str = "please visit http://www.sample.com for more infomation"

I have to display the underlined URL part alone like:

*http://www.sample.com*

TIA

Comment: Your examples doesn't match each other. You probably just need to use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url).

Comment: Would you like to take only URL part from string? Use Regular Expression.

Comment: This is bad design, you should but the URL in a separate variable

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression. Check below pattern, I hope this will work for you.

```
var str = "please visit http://www.sample.com for more infomation"

var result= str.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi);
```

Comment: https should be => http.

Comment: it shows exception in console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token